# Anyone using SRF08 ranger on address other then 0xF8?

Tags: ros, arduino, sonar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a **single** SRF08 ranger running on the supplied 0xF8 address, but I can't get it to work on the other addresses (I need several sensors).  I have verified the ranger to be addressed to 0xE8, but the ranger does not reply to either the programmed address 0xE8, or the +4 address the author uses for subsequent calls.

The author suggests:

New_Address += 4; // offset address not sure why this is but it works for this address

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/SRF08%20Ultrasonic%20Range%20Finder

I have implemented a multi-ranger program in the past (on a 2620 PIC), and I didn't need to do any "+4" trick to get it working.  It also worked on all six addresses.  I have not yet "ported" my my code to the Atmel (I wanted to use the Sonar_srf08 library).

There is a newer version of the library, but it's essentially the same, just added gain and range parameters to several wire.writes.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SonarSrf08

Any ideas or fixes?

Thanks,
Alan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59586/anyone-using-srf08-ranger-on-address-other-then-0xf8?/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the problem.  The SonarSRF08 library did not shift the I2C address right by one, so the addresses sent to Wire were wrong.

Wire.beginTransmission(address/2);
Wire.requestFrom(address/2, numBytes);

Now the +4 added to the address in the example (calling program) is not needed.  I have now added code to cycle through my three SRF08 Sonar modules.

Alan

---

Originally posted by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) with karma: 191 on 2013-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1